# polymerfire create uid path in firebase database for new loggedin user

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-realtime-database, polymerfire

I am new to polymer and firebase. I could not find good documentation on firebase-document element for polymer. 
My question is when a new user is logged in, how can I create an object in firebase database with his uid?

Also, please point me to some good examples on how to save and query the data using polymerfire firebase elements.

Comment: Asking for good external documentation is off topic here on Stack Overflow. It will get your question closed. Your other question is *on* topic. So if you remove the requests for links and add some examples of what you've already tried to have a better chance at getting a useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, you'll need [firebase-auth](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/polymerfire?active=firebase-auth) to make authentication magic happen. For example, if you want to do a Google login, you need:

1. Assign these properties to firebase-auth element

   ```
   <firebase-auth
     id="auth"
     user="{{user}}"
     provider="google"
     signed-in="{{signedIn}}">
   </firebase-auth>
   ```
2. Assign click/tap event listener to button

   ```
   <button on-tap="signInWithGoogle">Sign In With Google</button>
   ```
3. Call OAuth authentication method on button click/tap

   ```
   signInWithGoogle: function() {
     this.$.auth.signInWithPopup();
   }
   ```

Now, here's how you save user information to firebase database:

1. Assign these properties to [firebase-document](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/polymerfire?active=firebase-document) element (mind that `path` property is irrelevant at this point as it will be overridden with `save()` method)

   ```
   <firebase-document
      id="authDocument"
      data="{{userData}}">
   </firebase-document>
   ```
2. Extend `signInWithGoogle()` method

   ```
   signInWithGoogle: function() {

     // Chain then() method to the Promise
     this.$.auth.signInWithPopup().then(function(response) {

       // Update userData object with user information
       // returned with signInWithPopup()
       this.userData.displayName = response.user.displayName;
       this.userData.email = response.user.email;

       // Save userData object under /users/$uid. Note that at this
       // point authDocument's path is now changed to /users/$uid
       this.$.authDocument.save('/users', response.user.uid);

       // And don't forget to bind this
     }.bind(this));
   }
   ```

Hope that helped. Here's a full implementation in single element. Mind that firebase-app element is in parent.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-auth.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-document.html">

<dom-module id="my-account">

  <template>

    <style>

      :host {
        display: block;
      }

    </style>

    <firebase-auth
        id="auth"
        user="{{user}}"
        provider="google"
        signed-in="{{signedIn}}">
    </firebase-auth>

    <firebase-document
        id="authDocument"
        data="{{userData}}">
    </firebase-document>

    <div hidden$="[[user]]">
      <button on-tap="signInWithGoogle">Sign In With Google</button>
    </div>
    <div hidden$="[[!user]]">
      <table>
        <tr><th>photoURL</th> <td><img src="[[user.photoURL]]" alt=""></td></tr>
        <tr><th>uid</th> <td>[[user.uid]]</td></tr>
        <tr><th>displayName</th> <td>[[user.displayName]]</td></tr>
        <tr><th>email</th> <td>[[user.email]]</td></tr>
        <tr><th>emailVerified</th> <td>[[user.emailVerified]]</td></tr>
      </table>

      <button on-tap="signOut">Sign Out</button>
    </div>

  </template>

  <script>

    Polymer({

      is: 'my-account',

      signInWithGoogle: function() {
        this.$.auth.signInWithPopup().then(function(response) {
          this.userData.displayName = response.user.displayName;
          this.userData.email = response.user.email;
          this.$.authDocument.save('/users', response.user.uid);
        }.bind(this));
      },

      signOut: function() {
        this.$.auth.signOut();
      }
    });

  </script>

</dom-module>
```